# Is there a preferred practice for restricting code push to Git repositories?

Tags: git, repository, checkin

I have been researching methods of guarding Git repositories from getting accidental code pushes from a developer in a team environment.  Currently I have more questions then answers from researching.  I have used TFS and VSTS policy controls check-ins but I do not see this in Git or it is not easily found.

Does anyone have a good practice they are willing to share?

Comment: Create the "master" repository for your code. Then fork a separate repository from the "master" for the developer(s) you want to restrict. Then make them do pull requests to get code merged into the "master". If they've done something wrong, deny the PR. Git itself does not manage users.

Comment: Also, look into the use of a file called ".gitignore", so you do not accidentally check in files that you want to omit, like large binary, temp, or other files.  See:  https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, in Git, this is accomplished by controlling permissions on a per-repository level. Developers without permission to push can make pull requests or submit patches.

However, there is a way to get finer-grained access control. In Git this is accomplished through the `pre-receive` hook. This script is executed on your Git server whenever someone pushes to it, if the script exits with a nonzero status then the push will be rejected. You can use this to enforce any type of access control you want. However, writing a `pre-receive` hook to enforce your access control is not trivial, so it is more common to use some kind of software together with Git to control access—like GitHub, GitLab, Gerrit, or Gitolite.

- GitHub lets you restrict who can push to specific branches. See: https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/
- GitLab lets you protect branches in a similar way. See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html
- Gitolite lets you configure permissions. See: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf/
- Gerrit lets you force commits to go through code review before being merged. See: https://www.gerritcodereview.com/